# post request can't return an NSDictionary in swift

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I am making a `POST` request in swift, and my code cannot collect the data as an `NSDictionary`.

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.mindyour.money/individual_players_by_sport_history.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "token=\(token)&sport=\(sports)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?

        var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: nil) as? NSDictionary

        var json : JSON = JSON(data: data)
```

However, if I cast as `NSArray` this is easily picked up.  I have successfully managed to collect as an `NSDictionary` before, but only from an `NSData` object.  Could somebody help me?

An example of the son file should be something like this;

```
    [
  {
    "gametype" : "Football FantasyLeagueGame",
    "player_username" : "BarryManilow",
    "event" : "Rep. of Ireland v England - Coupon",
    "stake" : "5.00",
    "seat_created" : "2015-06-07 12:14:51",
    "game_end_time" : "2015-06-07 14:50:00",
    "numseats" : "1"
  }]
```

I use several of these key values to create a class array, later in the code, and I may have more questions later.  Apologies.

Comment: Maybe let postString = "?token=\(token)&sport=\(sports)";

Answer (score 0):

The JSON returned by the service is an array of games. In JSON, contents within `[...]` represent an array of items. `NSDictionary` can only represent a JSON object, which is what your JSON array contains. Because of this, the `id` returned by `JSONObjectWithData` should be cast to `NSArray`.

Comment: Thanks Nicklas, got it!!

Comment: For completeness, I changed the php to produce a JSON as follows;

{"trial":[
  {
    "gametype" : "Football FantasyLeagueGame",
    "player_username" : "BarryManilow",
    "event" : "Rep. of Ireland v England - Coupon",
    "stake" : "5.00",
    "seat_created" : "2015-06-07 12:14:51",
    "game_end_time" : "2015-06-07 14:50:00",
    "numseats" : "1"
  }]}

Then access items via if let for [NSDictionary]